# how to structure loop to check if object value doesn't exist in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a series of arrays containing objects, that contain arrays of objects...

```
const testArray = [
[
  {
    name: "object 1", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "name"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "age"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "object 2", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "age"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "location"}
    ]
  },
], 
[
  {
    name: "object 3", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "age"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "location"}
    ]
  }
]
]
```

I want to return only the arrays that contain objects whose elements don't include scope: "name". In the case above, it would return `testArray[1]`. I tried using `forEach` and `some()`, but it's not working.

```
//is called inside function that iterates over testArray
const generateNameField = arr => {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    const nameFieldFound = item.elements.some(el => el.scope === "name")
    if(!nameFieldFound){
      return arr
    }
  })
}
```

But because one of the objects doesn't contain `scope: "name"`, it returns that object. Can't seem to solve this, any help appreciated.

Comment: *"I want to return only the arrays that contain objects whose elements don't include `scope: "name"`. In the case above, it would return `testArray[1]`."* What is there's more than one?

Comment: Well, you're checking if `scope === "#/properties/name"` not `scope === "name"`. Also, returning from `forEach` does nothing. You probably want [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: If it encounters one, it will add an item to it, and continue iterating over the others. My mistake @HereticMonkey, edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'every'

```
const result=testArray.filter(e=>e.every(k=>k.elements.every(l=>l.scope!='name')))
```

Comment: I don't think the filter was necessary, but I was missing every. 
```
const generateNameField = arr => {
  const result = arr.every(obj =>
        obj.elements.every(({scope}) =>
            scope !== "#/properties/name"
        )
  );

  if(result){
    return arr
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `filter` while iterating over the whole `.testArray`, and use `.every` to check that any of the objects have arrays matching the condition (in addition to the `.some` for the `elements` - which would make more sense if changed around to `.every`):

```js
const testArray = [
[
  {
    name: "object 1", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "name"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "age"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "object 2", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "age"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "location"}
    ]
  },
], 
[
  {
    name: "object 3", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "age"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "location"}
    ]
  }
]
]

const generateNameField = arr => arr.filter(subarr => (
  subarr.every(item =>
    item.elements.every(el => el.scope !== "name")
  )
));
console.log(generateNameField(testArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've said you want it to find `testArray[1]`, but unless it's guaranteed that ther can only ever be one array with no `scope: "name"`, the usual operations are to either find the **first** with no `scope: "name"`, or an array of all of the matches (though of course other options are possible; those are just the common operations).

Those operations are embodied by [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), respectively.

Here's `find`, where within the subarray we use `every` to ensure every entry matches, and within `every` we use `every` to make sure every object's `elements` array matches. By "matches" I mean "doesn't have `scope: "name"`.

```
const result = testArray.find(subarray =>
    subarray.every(obj =>
        obj.elements.every(({scope}) =>
            scope !== "name"
        )
    )
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const testArray = [
[
  {
    name: "object 1", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "name"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "age"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "object 2", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "age"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "location"}
    ]
  },
], 
[
  {
    name: "object 3", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "age"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "location"}
    ]
  }
]
];

const result = testArray.find(subarray =>
    subarray.every(obj =>
        obj.elements.every(({scope}) =>
            scope !== "name"
        )
    )
);

console.log(result);
```

`filter` is the same other than the method we call and the fact it returns an array of matches:

```
const result = testArray.filter(subarray =>
    subarray.every(obj =>
        obj.elements.every(({scope}) =>
            scope !== "name"
        )
    )
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const testArray = [
[
  {
    name: "object 1", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "name"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "age"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "object 2", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "age"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "location"}
    ]
  },
], 
[
  {
    name: "object 3", 
    elements: [
      {type: "horizontal", scope: "age"},
      {type: "vertical", scope: "location"}
    ]
  }
]
];

const result = testArray.filter(subarray =>
    subarray.every(obj =>
        obj.elements.every(({scope}) =>
            scope !== "name"
        )
    )
);

console.log(result);
```